# Calculate angle with vertical in oblique triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I'm working on a double pendulum problem where I have to find a specific angle for implementation in MATLAB. I can find the angle that I need with basic trigonometry, but I was hoping that there is a fast and efficient way to find the angle with some kind of *trick*.

The angle I am looking for is `theta2` and all the labeled parameters are given.

[image: oblique triangle]

Note that $\alpha$ can rotate over its entire range so that $0 \leq \alpha \leq 2\pi$.

Also the length of $R$ is determined from user input x-y coordinates (intersection of $R$ and $L_2$) so thoe coordinates are also known.

Comment: The question is unclear. Are the lengths of $L_1,L_2,R$ known?

Comment: @Jack yes, those variables are indeed known.

Comment: I don't think $R$ is given.

Comment: @Narasimham it is given, it is calculated as the `norm` of the x,y coordinates of the intersection of $R$ and $L_2$. Those coordinates are user input.

Comment: @pseudoeuclidean $\beta$ was defined wrong in the first picture. I have updated it. It is the angle between the downward vertical and $R$

Comment: @Ortix92 Yeah, I just missed that edit

Comment: @Jack correct, I will update the picture again

Comment: Take your time and make all corrections in one go.

Comment: @Narasimham it should be correct now

Comment: Have you tried [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Since one knows all the three sides, one can [find](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html) all the three angles of the triangle.

Step 2: Now let $\gamma=\pi-\alpha-\beta$. Then $\gamma+\theta_2=\delta$ where $\delta$ is the angle between $L_1$ and $L_2$, which is done in Step 1.